# Is it possible to "lock" Word 365's scrolling to the middle of the page?

Tags: microsoft-word, scrolling, microsoft-word-365

When working on a document, the document will start scrolling when a new line reaches the bottom of the visible space, as shown [in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Yyw.jpg). Word will let the text fill the entire page before scrolling downwards, which is rather uncomfortable for my eyes, requiring me to focus on the bottom of the screen.

I'm looking for a way to make word start scrolling downwards when the text reaches the middle of the page, leaving about 50% of the bottom screen space blank, so that new lines will always be in the middle of the screen - "lock" the view to the middle, as shown in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iRf8.jpg).

Is this possible at all?

Comment: not an answer but possibly a great workaround: if you hover the mouse between both pages, you see this icon of a square with 2 arrows. If you double-click there, it will remove all the empty spaces and make it far more readable. with a line in between. Double click the line again to undo.

Comment: That's very neat and helpful actually! Thank you